# Automate a Python Script

Tags: automation, cron

I have a python script, uploaded on a web server which is up 24/7. I want to automate this script, so that it runs every hour automatically. Is this possible? I came across cron job stuff, but I am not familiar about how to achieve this. Any help or example would be helpful.

Comment: Is your question about [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples) then?

Comment: not python specific. search this site.

Comment: cron is really the best answer here.  There's definitely a learning curve but any other tool is going to be overkill and probably a cron wrapper of questionable additional value.

Comment: This may be probably be treated as a pythonic question - or maybe, can we consider a script as a script which is cron-ed periodically?

Comment: I'm not migrating this question anywhere. `cron` jobs are adequately covered all over SO and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your cron job file with

```
crontab -e
```

the add this line

```
* 0 * * *  /path/to/my/script
```

I would recommend using a bash script or something to check if the process is already running.

```
if [ `ps -u USERNAME | grep -i PROCESSNAME | wc -l` -lt 1 ]
then
  nohup python main.py &
fi
```

**Edit**

Type the command `crontab -e` then press enter. Your screen will go black with a bunch of `~`'s off to the side. Press `i` you are now in insert mode. Type `* 0 * * *  /path/to/my/script`, make sure this is the absolute path to your script. Press `Esc`, then type `:x` and press enter. That should save the cron file, that is also assuming that `vi` or `vim` is the default editor for your cron file.

*Side notes*

Also make sure that your script is executable, `chmod 777 myscript.py` should do the trick, however please familiarize yourself with chmod and permissions.

Also make sure that you have your `#/python/version/to/use` as the first line in your python file.

Comment: john, I have no idea about how to do this. All I know is that I have a file named program.py uploaded on the server and I want to execute it periodically..somebody told me that it can be done through cron job..and this is all i know. Can you please elaborate step by step?

Answer (score 1):

First:   Ask yourself if the data should be dynamic instead of static.  Dynamic data might be better accessed through a database or cgi script.

Second:  Read the manual a bit.   crontab is the program used to manage cron jobs.  A web search can give you more in depth info (knowing which nail to hit is half the battle).  man crontab isn't much help in planning, but can give pointers about the program if it doesn't edit the file as you expect.

Third: Determine where your python runs from by executing 'which python' and add the descriptor to the top of the file.  in my case it's #!/usr/bin/python

Fourth: Place your pyhton script in an appropriate place, perhaps /usr/local/sbin/ if it's important enough and you have permissions.   Make your file executable using chmod 775 on the file.   Run the file to make sure it executes as you expect.

Fifth:  Edit the cron job table table with crontab -e    If you can't run it as yourself, try running it under sudo (i.e. sudo crontab -e).

Sixth:  Add a line as  0 * * * * /myPath/myfile.py

This will run every time the minute changes to 00.   Wikipedia says @hourly should work, but I've never tried it.

Format is as follows

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 is Sunday)   
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Seventh:   Test test test.

crontab - l lists the cron job specifications.

There are environment variables such as $PYTHONPATH that may have to be present when cron executes.

If there are 6 fields in the crontab the first may be seconds.

Someday you want to log the output of seomthing.   Read about making a log file directory in /var/logs and how to manage it with the /etc/logrotate.d/ file.